How to name uppercase variables when using the camelCase convention?
I am writing a C# class and  one of the fields is an API endpoint. Being that API is an acronym and is written in all uppercase letters, what is the correct way to name the field _APIEndpoint, _apiEndpoint or _aPIEnpoint?

Questions about naming things are usually closed as opinion-based, but personally I think this question is answerable given that the maintainer of the C# language has explicit guidance (see JMekker's answer). That being said, all of your suggested names will compile just fine.

Note - for recent .NET versions, the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis NuGet Package and various settings in .editorconfig can enforce all kinds of coding style rules at compile time (and in many cases can auto-fix within the IDE) - See Here, here and here.

At least going by .NET naming guidelines, you should use _apiEndpoint if it is a field or ApiEndpoint if it is a property. Quoting from the link:

The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following examples: PropertyDescriptor HtmlTag


A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier: IOStream


It's also the only option that really works. _aPI just looks weird, and _API disrespects the rule of starting with a lower-case letter.

Do note that the leading underscore for the field is not part of the guidelines.

@BillTürstandswithUkraine Interesting. I've been seeing fields with the leading underscore for as long as I can remember. I never noticed it wasn't part of the guidelines.

@MetalMikester I guess that is beacuse (at least how I read it) the guidelines only deal with public members and the underscore is usually used for private ones.

JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest has always bugged me. Why uppercase XML but camelcase Http?

Mmm, IIRC guidelines are the same for Java too.

If you assume three-letter acronyms are special cased, it makes sense.

@Barmar it's because "XML" is pronounced with 3 distinct letters, but "Http" is pronounced "itch-puh"     - Ken M.

@Barmar Many years ago, I tried to push the standard described here on my team. Some people were unable to accept the idea of lowercasing initialisms as if there were normal words. Each letter is the beginning of a new word, or that's the best explanation I remember getting for their refusal to do it this way.

@BryanBoettcher Is this a joke? Do people actually pronounce it that way instead of H-T-T-P?

@JMekker yes that is a joke. The - Ken M part suggests that it is a made up quote attributed to a well known harmless and good natured troll who makes comments in a similar style.

I'd suggest a slightly different approach: It might be more interesting for the reader of your code to know which API is being accessed than that it is an API. So if you're accessing calendar events or booking information through that API, you'd name the field CalendarEndpoint or BookingEndpoint.
The .NET naming guidelines referenced in another answer explicitly recommend against hungarian notation and using acronyms in identifiers, so this would also indicate that a semantically meaningful name is preferable to a technical name.

Or if there's only one in context, just endpoint will suffice.

You shouldn't have to ask the question in the first place, since you should use (and enforce!) a common style.
Either the team you're part of already has a given style. In this case, refer to it, and do whatever it says. Note that it may say things you don't agree with—this doesn't really matter at the moment where you are writing your code, and you still have to follow it (otherwise, if things are set up correctly, you won't be able to commit your code anyway). If you don't agree with it, the given rule should be discussed with the team, and it belongs to the team to decide to replace a given rule by another.
Or there is no style set up—this can happen if this is a new project, or if you just started a personal project on your own. In this case, refer to the official style guide. Luckily, Microsoft does have one, and it tells you that _apiEndpoint is the correct option if you use recent versions of .NET and the default code analysis rules.
Note: if you use old StyleCop rules, then the correct answer would be apiEndpoint with lowercase a (SA1306), with no underscore (SA1309). The no-underscore rule remains in CA1707; however, it is not enabled by default, and it seems that underscored fields are now encouraged. Example:

Private instance fields start with an underscore (_).

Source: C# identifier naming rules and conventions
Anyway, all aforementioned sources agree on the fact that [_]apiEndpoint is the correct writing, and the fact that “API” is an acronym and should be written in all capitals in English is irrelevant here.

If you're using CamelCase, you only capitalise the first letter of acronyms.
My HTTP Client => MyHttpClient


This is at least the convention in C#. Other languages may have other opinions on this.
